# For loop results are only correct for the first iteration in R

Tags: r, for-loop, shapefile

**My project:**

I am looping through shapefiles in a folder, and running some calculations to add new columns with new values in the output shapefile

**My problem:**

The calculations are correct for the first iteration. However these values are then added as columns to every subsequent shapefile (rather than doing new calculations per iteration). Below is the code. The final columns resulting from this code running are: final_year, final_month, final_day, final_date.

**My code:**

```
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

input_path<- "/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/Zone_Fixup/Z4/Z4_Split/"
output_path<- "/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/Zone_Fixup/Z4/Z4_Split_Out/"

files<- list.files(input_path, pattern = "[.]shp$")

for(f in files){

  ifile<- list.files(input_path, f)
  shp_paste<- paste(input_path, ifile, sep = "")
  tryCatch({shp0<- readOGR(shp_paste, verbose=FALSE)}, error = function(e){print("Error1.")})


  #Order shapefile by filename
  shp1<- as.data.frame(shp0)
  shp2<- shp1[order(shp1$filename),]

  #Sort final dates by relative length values. 
  #If it's increasing, it's day1; if it's decreasing it's day3, etc.

  shp2$final_day1<- ifelse(lag(shp2$Length1)<shp2$Length1, paste0(shp2$day1), paste0(shp2$day3))
  shp2$final_month1<- ifelse(lag(shp2$Length1)<shp2$Length1, paste0(shp2$month1), paste0(shp2$month3))
  shp2$final_year1<- ifelse(lag(shp2$Length1)<shp2$Length1, paste0(shp2$year1), paste0(shp2$year3))

  #Remove first NA value of each column
  if(is.na(shp2$final_day1[1])){
    ex1<- shp2$day1[1]
    ex2<- as.character(ex1)
    ex3<- as.numeric(ex2)
    shp2$final_day1[1]<- ex2
  }
  if(is.na(shp2$final_month1[1])){
    ex4<- shp2$month1[1]
    ex5<- as.character(ex4)
    ex6<- as.numeric(ex5)
    shp2$final_month1[1]<- ex5
  }
  if(is.na(shp2$final_year1[1])){
    ex7<- shp2$year1[1]
    ex8<- as.character(ex7)
    ex9<- as.numeric(ex8)
    shp2$final_year1[1]<- ex9
  }

  #Add final dates to shapefile as new columns
  shp0$final_year<- shp2$final_year1
  shp0$final_month<- shp2$final_month1
  shp0$final_day<- shp2$final_day1
  final_paste<- paste(shp0$final_year, "_", shp0$final_month, "_", shp0$final_day, sep = "")
  shp0$final_date<- final_paste 

  #Create new shapefile for write out
  shp44<- shp0


  #Write out shapefile
  ifile1<- substring(ifile, 1, nchar(ifile)-4)
  #tryCatch({writeOGR(shp44, output_path, layer = ifile1, driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)}, error = function(e){print("Error2.")})
  test1<- head(shp44)
  print(test1)

}
```

**My results:** 
Here are two head() tables. The first table is correct. The second table is not correct. Notice that the final_year, final_month, final_day, and final_year columns are identical in the two tables. NOTE: These columns are the last four in the table

Table 1:

```
           coordinates  Length1     Bathy Vector                               filename  zone year1 year2 year3 month1 month2 month3 day1 day2 day3 final_year final_month final_day final_date
1 (-477786.3, 1110917) 29577.64 -6.455580      0 Zone4_2000_02_05_2000_02_15_2000_02_24 Zone4  2000  2000  2000     02     02     02   05   15   24       1997          02        15 1997_02_15
2 (-477786.3, 1110917) 29577.64 -6.455580      0 Zone4_2000_02_24_2000_03_10_2000_03_17 Zone4  2000  2000  2000     02     03     03   24   10   17       1997          03        26 1997_03_26
3 (-477848.2, 1113468) 27025.88 -2.100153      0 Zone4_2000_03_24_2000_04_03_2000_04_10 Zone4  2000  2000  2000     03     04     04   24   03   10       1997          04        19 1997_04_19
4   (-477871, 1114406) 26087.98 -4.700025      0 Zone4_2006_03_10_2006_03_27_2006_04_03 Zone4  2006  2006  2006     03     03     04   10   27   03       1998          02        08 1998_02_08
5 (-477876.1, 1114616) 25877.25 -7.598877      0 Zone4_2008_03_06_2008_03_16_2008_03_25 Zone4  2008  2008  2008     03     03     03   06   16   25       1998          03        28 1998_03_28
6 (-477878.8, 1114730) 25764.14 -7.598877      0 Zone4_2008_03_30_2008_04_09_2008_04_23 Zone4  2008  2008  2008     03     04     04   30   09   23       1998          04        21 1998_04_21
```

Table 2:

```
coordinates  Length1     Bathy Vector                               filename  zone year1 year2 year3 month1 month2 month3 day1 day2 day3 final_year final_month final_day final_date
1 (-477813.5, 1110939) 29612.26 -6.455580      1 Zone4_2000_02_05_2000_02_15_2000_02_24 Zone4  2000  2000  2000     02     02     02   05   15   24       1997          02        15 1997_02_15
2 (-477813.5, 1110939) 29612.26 -6.455580      1 Zone4_2000_02_24_2000_03_10_2000_03_17 Zone4  2000  2000  2000     02     03     03   24   10   17       1997          03        26 1997_03_26
3 (-477883.4, 1113392) 27158.05 -2.100153      1 Zone4_2000_03_24_2000_04_03_2000_04_10 Zone4  2000  2000  2000     03     04     04   24   03   10       1997          04        19 1997_04_19
4 (-477909.9, 1114319) 26230.17 -4.700025      1 Zone4_2006_03_10_2006_03_27_2006_04_03 Zone4  2006  2006  2006     03     03     04   10   27   03       1998          02        08 1998_02_08
5 (-477916.7, 1114558) 25991.57 -7.598877      1 Zone4_2008_03_06_2008_03_16_2008_03_25 Zone4  2008  2008  2008     03     03     03   06   16   25       1998          03        28 1998_03_28
6 (-477920.1, 1114678) 25871.39 -7.598877      1 Zone4_2008_03_30_2008_04_09_2008_04_23 Zone4  2008  2008  2008     03     04     04   30   09   23       1998          04        21 1998_04_21
```

It looks like my code is taking the column values from the first iteration and adding them to shapefiles in subsequent iterations. How can my code be modified to run new calculations with each iteration, and add those unique values to their respective shapefiles?

Thank you

Comment: Can yo please provide your data? I know it’s tough with shapefiles but at least a link to a similar shapefile or at minimum what does the unaltered data look like?

Comment: Not sure how to add the shapefiles but the unaltered data looks like the output tables without the last four columns: final_year, final_month, final_day, and final_date. So the output tables minus those four columns are the input attribute tables of the shapefiles. I use the values from the attribute tables to calculate the additional four columns in the output table.

Comment: This is unclear as you mention in each iteration *values are then added as columns* but show data that first two iterations are identical. What line adjusts shapefile? Maybe show desired result of 2nd iteration.

Comment: I had the code annotated to explain what's happening. For each row, there are multiple days/months/years. The "final" date in a given row is informed by the day/month/year values in that same row. For example, final_day is either day1, or day3 value in the same row. Whether day1 or day 3 is chosen is contingent on the relative values in the column "Length". In this column, if the value in the previous row is greater than the value in the row being considered, final_day is day1. If the length value in the previous row is less than the length value in the row being considered, final_day is day3

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be with the start of your for loop.

```
files<- list.files(input_path, pattern = "[.]shp$") #keep this line to get your files

for (f in 1:length(files)){ # change this to the length of files to iterate over files one by one

  ifile<- list.files(input_path, f) #delete this line from your code
  shp_paste<-paste(input_path,files[f],sep="") # use this line to iterate over each shp file
```

keep the rest of you code as it is and see if this helps..

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I did this and unfortunately still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, everyone, I found the problem. A tad embarrassing, I wasn't sorting the filename by ascending order before adding the new columns in. Therefore it seemed like the values in the new columns were wrong, because they weren't matched to the correct rows. A clumsy error on my part, thanks to all who offered advice.